# image not correctly overlapping with another image

Tags: html, css, web-deployment

My output is this

[image]

But I want the lower image to completely inline with the upper image thus creating a single image impression where lower part will be the lower image and upper part will be the upper image.
EDIT: I want : [image]

My html code :

```css
.shamne {
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.pichone {
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3 col-lg-6 col-12 mb-4">
  <div>
    <img src="images/fake_m.png" class="shamne" />
    <img src="images/tamim1.png" class="pichone" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you can look into:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/v5L3wdme/46/) to play around

```css
.row {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.shamne {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px solid blue;
}

.pichone {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div>
  <div class="row">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/301/301" class="shamne" />
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/201/201" class="pichone" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hey man, thanks for reply. but unfortunately i couldnt work your solution. I feel like i didnt make what i want clear. So here's what i want - <https://imgbb.com/>?

Comment: @MainulHossain, I am using my office laptop and the image is blocked, so can you add the image directly to the question?

Comment: kindly check now, i have added what i want

Comment: @MainulHossain check the answer now, though I don't have the actual images but the code functionality remains same, you just have to replace the images and play around.

Comment: hey man, yes it worked! i got help from you and another thread, combined them and got what i want, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use both the position as `position: absolute` and for the second image choose z-index higher than the first one ,hope it will works

Comment: hey man, thanks for reply. but unfortunately i couldnt work your solution. I feel like i didnt make what i want clear. So here's what i want - ibb.co/47XVPz6